# Change in voltage across an inductor bulb gets brighter

Tags: electricity, electromagnetic-induction

I am trying to understand ac and induction coils. One of the books I am using has the following diagram:
[image]

The question states that the value of the voltage is adjusted so that the bulb just lights up. What would be the effect on the bulb of increasing the p.d. of the current source.

My answer was that a higher voltage would lead to more current and so the bulb would go dim or out but the answer in the book is that the bulb would glow brighter. I don't understand because I though increasing voltage would mean an increasing back emf which would make the light go dim.

Could someone let me know where my error is?

Comment: What do they say the purpose of the switch is?

Comment: @Bob D there is a separate question asking what would happen to the brightness of the bulb if the switch was closed, I said it would increase because the electricity would be able to avoid the resistance of the coil

Comment: And that would be correct, except that it is the inductive reactance (impedance)  that would be shorted, not resistance. So let me get this straight. The question as posed was the effect of increasing the voltage of the voltage source at the left on bulb brightness given that the switch is open. Correct?

Comment: @BobD Yes, that is correct. Increasing the p.d. given the switch is open

Comment: Ok then that’s what I based my answer on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My answer was that a higher voltage would lead to more current and so
> the bulb would go dim or out but the answer in the book is that the
> bulb would glow brighter. I don't understand because I though
> increasing voltage would mean an increasing back emf which would make
> the light go dim.

Increasing the magnitude of the current does not increase the back emf of the inductor. Increasing the *frequency* of the current does. The relationship between voltage and current for an ideal inductor is

$$v(t)=L\frac{di(t)}{dt}$$

The brightness of the bulb depends on the complex impedance of the combination of the inductor and the bulb. That impedance depends on frequency, but not on the magnitude of the voltage supply.

The impedance of the inductor depends only on the inductance $L$ and the frequency $f$. The complex impedance of an ideal inductor, for a sinusoidal current of frequency $f$ in Hz, is in complex form.

$$Z_{L}=jX_L$$

where $X_{L}=2πfL$ is the inductive reactance (magnitude of impedance) and $j=\sqrt{-1}$.

For simplicity, assume the impedance of the bulb is pure resistance, so

$$Z_{B}=R$$

The equivalent series impedance is then

$$Z_{eq}=R+jX_L$$

The magnitude of the equivalent impedance is then

$$\vert Z\vert =\sqrt {X_{L}^{2}+R^2}$$

Then the magnitude of the rms current to the bulb is

$$\vert I_{rms}\vert=\frac{V_{rms}}{\sqrt {X_{L}^{2}+R^2}}$$

And is proportional to the magnitude of the voltage source. If the frequency is increased $X_L$ increases and the current decreases (the bulb dims).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The brightness of the bulb will depend on the amplitude of the current in the loop. A sum of voltage drops will give you a differential equation for the current:
$$L\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}+iR=V\sin\omega t.$$

Solve this and you will see that the amplitude of $i$ is directly proportional to the source voltage amplitude, $V$.

A more conceptual, intuitive approach would be that the impedence of the inductor is proportional to the frequency of the voltage source, but not the amplitude. So if the voltage amplitude increases, the current will increase.